# Clang Format - How to remove space between [ and ::namespace?

Tags: clang-format

Clang-format inserts pretty annoying whitespace in the example below:

`blahblah[ ::namespace]`

I want it to be formatted like this:

`blahblah[::namespace]`

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

I've tried setting `SpacesInSquareBrackets: false`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but while looking for one, I discovered `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on`, so thanks for that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `clang-format` 3.9.0, that space is no longer inserted. In fact, now you can't get that space back even with `SpacesInSquareBrackets: true`.